# Visual Studio Spaces issue

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Is there any way(settings or extensions) to get spaces and tabs to behave in the following way:

1. Any long string of spaces or tabs are treated as a single unit. If the cursor is at the end of the string, then it removes ALL the spaces, as if it were a single unit. I get tired of having to hit the backspace to remove spaces at then end of a function.

   );                                         *<- Cursor at *, a ton of space between ; and * that takes repeated back spaces to clear
2. When hitting tab, it will insert the largest amount of space to match the previous lines columns indentation, excluding any empty lines.

So

```
This is a test                    //

and another <tab>                 *// Jumps to here, rather than having to hit it tab mulitple times.
```

3. When hitting enter, the cursor always indents the previous indentation amount, using tabs.
4. When starting a new block(with {) the next line is indented, when ending a block it is de-indented.

That's all I want. I've never been able to these types of features in visual studio. I want tabs to be 4 spaces by default but also to grow or shrink depending on context. Backspace always consumes as much whitespace as possible on the given line, and tab will try to align columns if it detects the previous non-empty line has column like characteristics(text separated by tabs or multiple spaces).

It would be nice also, if tabs were auto aligned. That is, when I have something nice and formatted and have to modify, say, an identifier name, I have to almost always fix the columns, it's very annoying and time consuming sometimes.

If there is nothing like this, are there any open source extensions that could be be modified to create this behavior easily?

Comment: Ctrl+K/Ctrl+D - format document - removes all trailing spaces. Ctrl+Backspace - removes word or many spaces.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I'd prefer not having to jump through hoops for something that can be automatically done.